# Select max column from joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The joined tables will result as a view like below. I wish to select just 1 record of the max id or prod_month column.

```
con_model srt_value_current con_id prod_month id
model   4   49  37  45145
model   4   49  38  45726
    
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.DM_TBL_CONFIGURATION_MODEL.con_model, dbo.SRT_Data.SRT_VALUE_CURRENT, dbo.DM_TBL_CONFIGURATION_MODEL.con_id, dbo.SRT_Data.ID, dbo.SRT_Data.PROD_MONTH
FROM            dbo.DM_TBL_CONFIGURATION_MODEL LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SRT_ItemNumbers ON dbo.DM_TBL_CONFIGURATION_MODEL.con_model = dbo.SRT_ItemNumbers.ITEM_NUMBER LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SRT_Data ON dbo.SRT_ItemNumbers.ID = dbo.SRT_Data.ITEM_NUMBER_ID
        WHERE (SRT_Data.id) IN 
                            ( SELECT MAX(id)
                              FROM SRT_Data
                            )
                            and con_model='model'
```

Comment: Sub-query `select top 1 * from ({existing query})`?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: By the way, learn about aliases, they will make your life easier. And `TOP (100) PERCENT` what do you think that is supposed to do??

Comment: Forget you ever learned about `TOP (100) PERCENT` - it does nothing useful. If you define a view with it, the engine knows it can (and does) safely ignore it. Views, like tables, are unordered definition.

Comment: OK thanks. As I am using the auto-generate View from SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Cross Apply.

```
             SELECT *
                    FROM dbo.DM_TBL_CONFIGURATION_MODEL a CROSS APPLY 
                        (
                            Select  Top 1 b.ID,dbo.SRT_Data.SRT_VALUE_CURRENT
                            From     dbo.SRT_ItemNumbers b LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SRT_Data ON b.ID = dbo.SRT_Data.ITEM_NUMBER_ID
                            Where   b.ITEM_NUMBER = a.con_model
                            Order By ID Desc
                      ) X
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row, use `TOP (1)`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) cm.con_model, s.SRT_VALUE_CURRENT, cm.con_id, s.ID, s.PROD_MONTH
FROM dbo.DM_TBL_CONFIGURATION_MODEL cm LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.SRT_ItemNumbers i
     ON cmL.con_model = i.ITEM_NUMBER LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.SRT_Data s
     ON i.ID = s.ITEM_NUMBER_ID
WHERE cm.con_model = 'model' 
ORDER BY s.prod_month DESC;
```

Comment: It doesn't really fulfill my requirement as I am using View here. It will only show 1 top record from the joined tables.

Comment: @JL_Coder . . . I have no idea what your comment means.  The query is the same regardless of whether the references are to tables or views.